# MultiAutoCompleteTextView deleting entire word on backspace

Tags: android, android-edittext, multiautocompletetextview

On a MultiAutoCompleteTextView in android I am able to add entries and parse them just fine. After auto completing the most recent item, when I press backspace it will delete all the characters before I autocomplete,
but I want to delete character one by one on backspace